# Problema con menú en Python

Tags: python, while

Hice un programa para graficar tres funciones con Python y que al hacerlo me regrese al menú principal. Esto último funciona, pero no me muestra la gráfica.

¿Qué puedo hacer que muestre la gráfica y luego me regrese al menú principal?

```
# Menú de graficación 2D

import math
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

while True:

    print('Menú de graficación 2D')
    print('1. y=x**2')
    print('2. y=sin(x)')
    print('3. y=exp(x)')
    
    opcion=int(input('Elije la función a graficar: '))
    xmin=float(input('Valor mínimo de x: '))
    xmax=float(input('Valor máximo de x: '))
    x=np.linspace(xmin,xmax,200)
    
    if opcion==1:
        y =x**2
        plt.title('Gráfica de y=x**2')
        continue
    elif opcion==2:
        y=np.sin(x)
        plt.title('Gráfica de y=sin(x)')
        continue
    else:
        y=np.exp(x)
        plt.title('Gráfica de y=exp(x)')
        plt.plot(x,y)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Por que pones `continue`?

Comment: Solo creas la gráfica en el bloque `else`

Comment: Pensé que esa sería la solución: colocar `continue`, pero ya vi que el error se debe a que los comandos `plt.plot(x,y)` y `plt.show()` están mal alineados. Gracias.